# Replace \\ command only within \chapter

Tags: strings

I am converting .tex files to .epub. I need to selectively replace the string "\\" ONLY within chapters command to a single blank space.

example:

```
\chapter{My title \\ on two rows}
```

becomes:

```
\chapter{My title on two rows}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: what class do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible! Just use regex.

E.g. `(\\chapter\{.*)\\\\` and then `$1` to recall the group. If you have more than one \ use more groups. (`(\\chapter\{.*)\\\\(.*)\\\\` and then `$1$2` and so on.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your method won't work on systems (such as Windows) that don't support grep or some other regex-capable utility. Moreover, the OP didn't say that he/she wants to strip out the `\\` instances permanently; she should be removed only if compilation to epub is being performed.

Comment: I use windows and used notepad++ to come up with this solution. Also op did not specify how he compiles his code, so I offered the solution that is always applicable.

Comment: You should state in the body of the answer how you use the regex-based approach.

Comment: Actually the op asked if it is possible and I said yes and gave a proof most people understand. The beauty of regex based approaches is that you can use them in so many different ways. Probably one will fit ops needs. I can see that my answer in contrast to yours is not 'plug and play' but still applicable in many contexts.

Comment: Sorry or my late reply. yes it works!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. If you don't want the `\\` items to be stripped from the arguments of `\chapter`, simply comment out the lua-related code.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function strike_double_backslash ( line )
   if string.find ( line, '\\chapter') then
      return ( string.gsub ( line, '\\\\', ' ') )
   end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback ( "process_input_buffer", 
   strike_double_backslash, "strike_double_backslash" )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title (no \\ longer!) on 2 rows}
\end{document}
```